# Fetch the last value of two variables from MSSQL cursor LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am having problems with a cursor loop in SQL server. I am trying to get two variables from the last iteration and use the in the next iteration. This is my query:

```
DECLARE @goodid int;
DECLARE goodIDCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT GoodID from Operations
OPEN goodIDCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM goodIDCursor INTO @goodid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @date varchar(20);
    DECLARE @qtty float;
    DECLARE @pricein float;
    DECLARE @qtty1 float;
    SET @qtty1 = 0;
    DECLARE @pricein1 float;
    SET @pricein1 = 0;
    DECLARE dateCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT Date from Operations where GoodID = @goodid ORDER BY Date
    OPEN dateCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM dateCursor INTO @date
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

        SET @qtty = (SELECT SUM(Qtty) from Operations WHERE Date = @date and GoodID = @goodid and Sign = 1 AND OperType NOT IN (7,8,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,25,33,35,36));

        SET @pricein = (SELECT (SUM(Qtty*PriceIn))/SUM(Qtty) from Operations WHERE Date = @date and GoodID = @goodid and Sign = 1 AND OperType NOT IN (7,8,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,25,33,35,36));

        UPDATE Operations SET PriceIn = ((@qtty1*@pricein1) + (@qtty*@pricein))/(@qtty1+@qtty) WHERE GoodID = @goodid and Date = @date and Sign = -1 AND OperType NOT IN (7,8,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,25,33,35,36);

        SET @pricein1 = ((@qtty1*@pricein1) + (@qtty*@pricein))/(@qtty1+@qtty);
        SET @qtty1 = @qtty1 + (SELECT SUM(Qtty*Sign) FROM Operations WHERE Date = @date and GoodID = @goodid);


    FETCH NEXT FROM dateCursor
    INTO @date
    END
    CLOSE dateCursor
    DEALLOCATE dateCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM goodIDCursor
INTO @goodid
END
CLOSE goodIDCursor
DEALLOCATE goodIDCursor
```

So, from all those things here the thing which should happen in the second loop is this:
In the beginning I want the variables @qtty1 and @ pricein1 to be 0. After teh first loop they should become:

```
@pricein1 = ((@qtty1*@pricein1) + (@qtty*@pricein))/(@qtty1+@qtty);
@qtty1 = @qtty1 + (SELECT SUM(Qtty*Sign) FROM Operations WHERE Date = @date and GoodID = @goodid);
```

and they must be accessible for the next iteration and so on. Every time it is iterating their values will be changes based on the calculations before and used for the next iteration.

Comment: What you really need to do is get rid of this nested cursor concept for updates entirely. This can and should be completely rewritten as a single set based update.

Comment: If you wanted to add sample records and expected output to your question we might be able to help you move away from cursors, which can be painfully slow in SQL.  If you *must* stick with cursors then it sounds like you need to move cursor B inside cursor A.  See example B near the bottom of this page on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx).  But be warned, you are missing out on the true power of SQL.

Comment: I must not stick with cursors. I will give you some sample data to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Treating your question as academic, and assuming I understand your question correctly, you can solve it with a Loop Counter variable, and only set the variables when the Loop Counter is 1.

Before the inner loop:

```
DECLARE @LC int = 1;
```

In the inner loop:

```
IF @LC = 1
 BEGIN
 SET @pricein1 = ((@qtty1*@pricein1) + (@qtty*@pricein))/(@qtty1+@qtty);
 SET @qtty1 = @qtty1 + (SELECT SUM(Qtty*Sign) FROM Operations WHERE Date = @date and GoodID = @goodid);
 END
```

Right before the end of the inner loop:

```
 SET @LC = LC + 1;
```

So for each iteration of the outer loop, you will set those two variables once for the first iteration of the inner loop, and then they will stay the same until the next iteration of the outer loop.

If that's not what you're after, then your question wasn't clear to me.